# Symfony4 - sharing cache pool between two entity managers, is it a bad idea or do I encounter a bug?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, entitymanager, profiler

it is going to be lengthy post, I encountering weird behavior where I see in profiler that one entity managers is said to map entity that it does not map. It looks like this:
[image: bottom of doctrine section in profiler]
Here is doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "127.0.0.1"
                port:     "3306"
                dbname:   "example"
                user:     "root"
                password: ""
                charset:  utf8mb4
                server_version: "mariadb-10.4.10"
            logs:
                driver:   "pdo_mysql"
                host:     "127.0.0.1"
                port:     "3306"
                dbname:   "example_logs"
                user:     "root"
                password: ""
                charset:  utf8mb4
                server_version: "mariadb-10.4.10"
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: App
            logs:
                query_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                metadata_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                result_cache_driver:
                    type: pool
                    pool: apcu.default.cache.pool
                connection: logs
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    LogBundle:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Logs'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Logs'
                        alias: App
```

And here is framework.yaml with cache pool configuration:

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax

    php_errors:
        log: true

    cache:
        pools:
            apcu.default.cache.pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
            apcu.logs.cache.pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.apcu
```

If I remove `metadata_cache_driver` configuration from logs `entity_manager` configuration, or change it to use different cache pool (apcu.logs.cache.pool) than default entity manager then profiler reports correct mappings (Example entity in default em and logs em is empty).

The issue occurs only when entity is feed trough form and `$form->handleRequest()` handles it, creating or modifying entity without forms does not cause such issue. Here is my controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Main\Example;
use App\Form\Type\ExampleType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ExampleController extends AbstractController {
    /**
     * @Route("/example1")
     * @Template
     */
    public function example1(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $example = new Example();
        $example->setValue('example value');

        try {
            $em->persist($example);
            $em->flush();
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            return new Response('An error has occurred. '.$e->getMessage());
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/example2")
     * @Template
     */
    public function example2(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $example = $em->getRepository(Example::class)->find(1);
        if(!$example){
            return new Response('No example found.');
        }

        $example->setValue(mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax()));
        try {
            $em->flush();
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            return new Response('An error has occurred. '.$e->getMessage());
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/example3")
     * @Template
     */
    public function example3(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $example = $em->getRepository(Example::class)->find(1);
        if(!$example){
            return new Response('No example found.');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(ExampleType::class, $example);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $em->flush();
        }

        return ['form' => $form->createView()];
    }


}
```

example1 and example2 routes **DOES NOT** cause issue, only example3 does and only when the form is submitted, so only when I enter example3 url, then click submit form only then when enter profiler for this request I can see the issue.

My minimal reproduction example was to create new symfony LTS project `symfony new example-site --version=lts --full`

Then these are files that I have changed since:

[image: file changes]

Databases are created by `symfony console doctrine:database:create --connection=default` and `symfony console doctrine:database:create --connection=logs` then tables are created by `symfony console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=default` and `symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=default`

Here is code for other files I haven't yet included in post:

```php
<?php
//src/Entity/Main/Example.php
namespace App\Entity\Main;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Example {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $value;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(){
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value){
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
//src/Form/Type/ExampleType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Main\Example;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ExampleType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('value', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Example::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- template/s/example/example1.html.twig -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Example1
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- template/s/example/example2.html.twig -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    Example2
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!-- template/s/example/example3.html.twig -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ form(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

Last thing I want to add is that in other project this issue is more visible, because when entity has reference to other entity an error is reported (on non-owning side in One-to-Many self-referencing association):
[image: other example with an error reported]
In this case Item entity is the one feed trough form.
For those who are curious here is Item.php:
But I don't know how would it matter as it is not managed by logs entity manager and should not appear under. default entity manager who is managing the entity is not reporting any issues with it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ItemRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={
 *          @ORM\Index(name="item_image", columns={"image"})
 *     })
 */
class Item {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=32)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $description = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item", mappedBy="container")
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="container", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var $container Item
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\TagItem", mappedBy="item")
     * @var $tags TagItem[]
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @Assert\Image(mimeTypes="image/jpeg")
     * @var $imageFile null|UploadedFile
     */
    private $imageFile;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->items = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDescription(){
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description){
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function hasImage(){
        return isset($this->image);
    }

    public function getImage(){
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage($image){
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function hasImageFile(){
        return isset($this->imageFile);
    }

    public function getImageFile(){
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImageFile($imageFile){
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
    }

    public function getItems(){
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function hasContainer(){
        return isset($this->container);
    }

    public function getContainer(){
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function setContainer(?Item $container){
        return $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getTags(){
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function setTags($tags){
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }
}
```

PHP version is 7.3.12 and hosted with `symfony serve`

Comment: what does your Item entity look like? because you post lots of other stuff, but the Item entity has a problem. and it might be somewhat unrelated. also your orm config is weird, you have additional entity managers that point to dirs/classes, that are not used ... how are those relevant?

Comment: @Jakumi, I have added it to end of my post. But I don't know how can that matter, Item entity is managed by default em, not logs em so it should not appear under logs em mappings, and on top of that default em does not report any issues with Item entity.

Comment: @Jakumi, to answer to your comment edit, Item entity is of another project added as other example how things can go wrong in profiler. Other than that my post contains all files the example needs to reproduce issue, in the example "logs" em is not managing any entities at this point, because it is not necessary to reproduce the issue, it is just there to exist as secondary em where entities that not belong appear under in profiler.

Comment: one aspect is, that the Item entity doesn't really belong to any entity manager (because neither includes it). it still somehow is an entity and will probably be put into *some* entity manager but this is just a weird construction at this point tbh, and I wouldn't be completely baffled if somewhere along the way this all falls apart. I'm also quite confused on how symfony knows which entity manager to provide when you ask for `EntityManagerInterface`, but I guess the default one ... I would probably not share a cache because an entity manager might clear it, and you possibly have collisions?

Comment: @Jakumi Item entity is not in example-site project, it is in other project I have same issue with. For now I will use different pools for each em and have been told to fill bug report, will get back on it if it will turn out to be one or misuse of the framework. Thank you for taking time to look into it.

Comment: @Jakumi you are right, `EntityManagerInterface` is aliased to `default_entity_manager`. In a multiple entity manager scenario you should either configure the dependency explicitly or inject `ManagerRegistry` and retrieve the correct one using `getManagerForClass()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back on github in [issue thread](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36318) from **fancyweb** who said:

> Status: reviewed
>
> The bug is unrelated to the WebProfilerBundle. The reason is that you use the same cache salt for the 2 entity managers. At some places, we blindly call getClassMetadata() on both EM sequentially (ie: DoctrineLoader, DoctrineExtractor). The first call on the rightful EM populates the cache. The second call on the EM that should not know the class hits the cache and thus considers the class as loaded.
>
> Using the same cache is fine, you just need to use different salts.

And when asked how if there is option in configuration to set salt for for entity manager I got answer from **stof**:

> The clean way to achieve that is to use 2 separate cache pools, as FrameworkBundle takes the pool name into account for the seed to isolate keys from each pool when they share the same storage.